# Removing lines around associated defined lines

Tags: python, regex

Could anyone help me with a simple script which would take the contents of a text file (content snippet example note: there are many more of this in that same file):
https://propaste.io/raw/SofuCbMiLY

And i would like it to turn into this:
https://propaste.io/raw/oMHjXveV3P

Effectively, removing all the lines invovled with the 'Purchased Links: 0', while keeping the others formatted nicely

I have tried the following script, it removes all formatting and becomes quite a mess:

```
#place the file in the same folder as this script and name it combo.txt

with open('combo.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()

content = content.split("---------")
output = open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf8")
for details in content:
    if "Purchased Link: 0" in details:
        continue
    else:
        output.write(details)
    output.write("\n")

output.close()
```

All help is appreciated! :)

Comment: What language do you want this script in?

Comment: @Jeto yes, thank you for the correction. My apologies. 
Nigel Ren Python

Comment: The "lines related to 'Purchased Link: 0'" in your code can be widely scattered about. To find them, you'd have to do much of what compiler optimization calls "data flow analysis". Definitely not a trivial task. Dig in with your favored editor. Use version control and check each step!

Answer (score 0):

All the entries are actually separated by two new lines, so you could just split on `"\n\n"` instead.

```
with open('combo.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as content_file:
    content = content_file.read().split("\n\n")

with open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf8") as output:
    output.write('\n\n'.join(x for x in content if "Purchased Link: 0" not in x))
```